# Azure Data Factory Mapping Data Flow: Epoch timestamp to Datetime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON-based source I'd like to transform using ADF Mapping Data Flow. I have a string containing an epoch timestamp value that I want to transform to Datetime value to later sink it into Parquet file.

Do you know a way? Docs of this language are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions).

Source file:

```
{
  "timestamp":"1574127407",
  "name":"D.A."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use toTimestamp() and set the formatting you wish as 2nd parameter

`toTimestamp(1574127407*1000l)`

From string:

`toTimestamp(toInteger(toString(byName('timestamp')))*1000l,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: Thanks Daniel ... One more slightly more elegant update to this solution:

toTimestamp(seconds(toInteger(toString(byName('timestamp')))),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

Comment: Thank you very much for you help Mark, it worked nice! I have never seen that technique before. Much appreaciated!

Comment: If you have a fully qualified timestamp in milliseconds, toInteger will not suffice (it overflows and fails silently), for that there's a `toLong` function: `toTimestamp(toLong(toString(byName('timestamp_milliseconds'))),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`

Answer (score 0):

I have came across various epoch timestamp values which are of 13 digits i.e., they even have milliseconds detailed information.

In such case, converting to integer using 'toInteger' won't serve the purpose instead this will keep the values as NULL. So, to fix this issue, we need to convert it to Long using toLong as below:

```
toTimestamp(toLong(toString(created)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

In above expression, 'created' is a field whose value is 13-digit epoch timestamp, something like this created='1635359043307'.

Here, toTimestamp returns the Date Timestamp with above-mentioned date format.

FYI, you can use this site https://www.epochconverter.com/ to check epoch timestamp to human date.